# How to bulk remove styles in wordpress post content by phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

There are useless styles in my 40,000 post content (Wordpress) as below,

```
<span style="font-family: Arial; color: #0066cc;">content</span>;
```

Anyone can tell me how to remove the style part to something as below?

```
<span>content</span>;
```

I tried the code below in cooresponding database in SQL under phpMyadmin

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, ' style="font-family: Arial; color: #0066cc;"', '' );
```

but was responded

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' style="font-family: Arial)' at line 1

Can anyone tell me how should I modify it?

Comment: Actually your given SQL code doesn't contain any syntax error. May be you tried different query in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: no syntax error in your code..its executed properly

Answer (score 1):

Use WP-CLI http://wp-cli.org/

It has a search replace function, the command you'd run would look like this on the command line. Honestly there's no other easy way to do it.

```
./wp-cli.phar search-replace 'style="font-family: Arial; color: #0066cc;"' ''
```

Comment: wp-cli may make the operation simpler, but that's completely false that an sql query can't do such replacements.

Comment: True, for the record it's almost 5am and I've been up all night, that's my excuse and I'm sticking to it! lol